# How to filter Column Headers?

Tags: reactjs, api

How to fetch column headers like data and do filter Column Headers when making API calls in React? I want to filter some Column Headers not to include them on my list.

```
const loadData = async () => {
    
                    return await axios
            .get("https://192.168.1.3:9200/clientesafewindows-logstash2/_search?")
            .then((response) => {

                // // Get Columns based on the data provided
                const list = response.data || []
                const firstObject = list[1] || {}
                const cols = []
                    for (const key in firstObject) {
                        const col = {
                            title: key,
                            dataIndex:key
                        }
                        cols.push(col)
                    }
                        setColumns(cols);
                        console.log('col is ',cols);


                setData(response.data)
                // dataVal.current = response;
                console.log(data);
                dataVal.current = response.data;
                
                // console.log(dataVal.current.hits.hits[1]);
                setCurrentPage(currentPage + increase);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the data you get in `response.data`?

Comment: I have got all the data in the console, but col is an empty array